# How to hide and show div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am developing a Bootstrap website for CI-testing. I have created a div, #chooseTest with a drop-down menu, with which the user can choose what kind of test that shall be performed.

**Edit:** *The file is a .hbs file (handlebars).  After some digging, I realized that the .js file with the jQuery, isn't even running...*

[The website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODBxE.jpg)

When the user has made a choice, #chooseTest should not be visible (which it still is: the Div with the drop-down menu under the textfields). And the appropriate div should be visible in its place: #mavenForm for example (the div with the checkboxes: Find bugs & check style).

Nothing is working right now. #mavenForm is visible when the website is launched and the drop-down menu is only for show. What is wrong with the code?

```js
 $(function () {
    $("#mavenForm").hide();

    $("#dropDownJava").click(function () {
        $("#chooseTest").hide();
        $("#mavenForm").show();

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gitForm">
        <div class="Aligner">
            <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class=card>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <form class="form-create" action="/" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="nameLabel" for="projectNameInput">Name your
                                        project</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobname" id="projectNameInput"
                                           placeholder="Enter a A project name you can live with">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="gitLabel" for="repoInput">Enter your Git
                                        repository</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gitrep" id=repoInput
                                           placeholder="A valid Gitrepo...">
                                </div>

<!-- The div #chooseTest which is to be replaced -->
                                <div id="chooseTest">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Choose Test
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-item" id="dropDownJava"
                                               href="#mavenForm">Java</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<!-- The div #mavenForm that shouldn't be visible when the website launches -->
                                <div id="mavenForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="FindBugs">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">FindBugs</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="CheckStyle">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">CheckStyle</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
```

Comment: What is not working? Is there error in console? Because your `code` working in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L6o0s1j/)

Comment: The file is a .hbs file (handlebars). After some digging, I realized that the .js file with the jQuery, isn't even running...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine with jQuery 2.1.1 and your jQuery function in a page ready function. See the snippet below to see:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#mavenForm").hide();  
    $("#dropDownJava").click(function(){
        $("#chooseTest").hide();
        $("#mavenForm").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gitForm">
        <div class="Aligner">
            <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class=card>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <form class="form-create" action="/" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="nameLabel" for="projectNameInput">Name your
                                        project</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobname" id="projectNameInput"
                                           placeholder="Enter a A project name you can live with">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="gitLabel" for="repoInput">Enter your Git
                                        repository</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gitrep" id=repoInput
                                           placeholder="A valid Gitrepo...">
                                </div>

<!-- The div #chooseTest which is to be replaced -->
                                <div id="chooseTest">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Choose Test
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-item" id="dropDownJava"
                                               href="#mavenForm">Java</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<!-- The div #mavenForm that shouldn't be visible when the website launches -->
                                <div id="mavenForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="FindBugs">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">FindBugs</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="CheckStyle">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">CheckStyle</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
```

Comment: Yes! Nothing was wrong with the code itself, but I had to use script tags in the .hbs file to get it running!

Answer (score 0):

based on JQuery documentation : 
"A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).on( "load", function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready."

Another test on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1v14syto/

So what you need to do is to surround your jquery code by $( document ).ready(function(){ /* Your Code */ })

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mavenForm').hide();  
    $('#dropDownJava').click(function(){
        $('#chooseTest').hide();
        $('#mavenForm').show();

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="gitForm">
        <div class="Aligner">
            <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class=card>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <form class="form-create" action="/" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="nameLabel" for="projectNameInput">Name your
                                        project</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobname" id="projectNameInput"
                                           placeholder="Enter a A project name you can live with">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label id="gitLabel" for="repoInput">Enter your Git
                                        repository</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gitrep" id=repoInput
                                           placeholder="A valid Gitrepo...">
                                </div>

<!-- The div #chooseTest which is to be replaced -->
                                <div id="chooseTest">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Choose Test
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-item" id="dropDownJava"
                                               href="#mavenForm">Java</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<!-- The div #mavenForm that shouldn't be visible when the website launches -->
                                <div id="mavenForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="FindBugs">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">FindBugs</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="CheckStyle">
                                                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                                                <span class="custom-control-description ml-4">CheckStyle</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
```